# An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Package name must look like: com.company.Name

Tags: android, windows-8, cordova

I created a phonegap project using

```
phonegap create trial4 --id com.geeroo.trial4 PhoneGapTrial4
```

On running

```
phonegap run android
```

Got the following error

```
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 
Package name must look like: com.company.Name
```

What does this error signify? My package name is already in the format required.

OS: Windows 8

Comment: see this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html

Comment: Have you specified your package name on config.xml?

Comment: What is the `--id` for? It should just be `phonegap create trial4 com.geero.trial4 PhoneGapTrial4`. It's giving you that error because it thinks you are trying to built an Android application in the package `--id` which is not a valid package name.

Comment: I had forgotten to specify --name before the Application name. Silly mistake really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should be

```
phonegap create trial4 --id "com.geeroo.trial4" --name "PhoneGapTrial4"
```

> --name

was missing from the command I was trying.

Working now.

Answer (score 1):

set  in config file :

the name of id with this format `' id="com.appName.companyName" '`

and name `' name> com.appName.companyName <name '`